# Jquery mobile grid layout with text areas

Tags: jquery-mobile, textarea, grid-layout

I need to create a a 2x2 grid for a mobile website where the cells are text areas. The problem is that when I do this there doesn't seem to be a way where the text boxes all join together at the inner-most corner. All I am able to achieve is two separate text boxes on top of two other separate text boxes none of which are touching vertically of horizontally. I have tried to manipulate the margins, padding, and borders, but nothing works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/cGt2J/

**CSS used:**

```
.ui-input-text {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
}
```